# Why do I not have a `_Total` performance counter instance?

Tags: c#, windows, performancecounter

I am creating a multi-instance performance counter with the following registration code, but do not seem to have a `_Total` instance — even when I have multiple active instances.  What do I need to do to get a total?

Registration code:

```
var slc = new CounterCreationDataCollection();
slc.Add(new CounterCreationData()
{
    CounterName = "Channels Open",
    CounterType = PerformanceCounterType.NumberOfItems32,
    CounterHelp = "Number of channels that have not been cleaned up."
});
PerformanceCounterCategory.Create("Frob", "Monitors the frob", 
    PerformanceCounterCategoryType.MultiInstance, slc);
```

Reporting code:

```
var channelName = "Widget 6";
var pcOpen = new PerformanceCounter("Frob", "Channels Open", channelName, false);

// elsewhere
pcOpen.Increment();

// followed by
pcOpen.Decrement();
```

Produces:

[image: Image showing my counter without a total]

Comment: Can you show a version with the instances non blured?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, They just show the names of various internal applications.  Imagine `contoso.ap.poLineManager` `contoso.ar.collectionsHelper`, etc...

Comment: AFAIK, There is nothing that makes those instances automatically. You've got to do it yourself. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1659429/517852).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the `_Total` counter is just another instance where they sum up the totals manually. The reason it has a leading `_` is so it is alphabetically before the `<` in `<All instances>` which is a "meta" counter.

```
var pc5Name = "Widget 5";
var pc6Name = "Widget 6";
var pc5 = new PerformanceCounter("Frob", "Channels Open", pc5Name, false);
var pc6 = new PerformanceCounter("Frob", "Channels Open", pc6Name, false);
var pcTotal = new PerformanceCounter("Frob", "Channels Open", "_Total", false);

// elsewhere
pc5.Increment();
pcTotal.Increment()

// more elsewhere
pc6.Increment();
pcTotal.Increment()

// followed by
pc5.Decrement();
pcTotal.Decrement();
```

Comment: Looks like you are right.  There are many variations (`_Total`, `_total`, `__Total__`, `_Global_`).  The reference source also backs this idea up: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/_NetworkingPerfCounters.cs#262